# How to configure AWS ECS Fargate Tasks/Cluster to access private Docker Container Registry (like GitHub Container Registry) with Pulumi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, aws-fargate, pulumi

I'am working on a AWS Fargate Cluster setup with Pulumi and my current program already successfully creates a Cluster incl. Fargate Tasks that run a public accessible container image. My image is based on Spring Boot ([project code on GitHub](https://github.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot)):

```
import * as awsx from "@pulumi/awsx";

// Spring Boot Apps port
const port = 8098;

// Create a ApplicationLoadBalancer to listen for requests and route them to the container.
const alb = new awsx.lb.ApplicationLoadBalancer("fargateAlb");

const albTargetGroup = alb.createTargetGroup("fargateAlbTargetGroup", {
    port: port,
    protocol: "HTTP",
    healthCheck: {
        // Use the default spring-boot-actuator health endpoint
        path: "/actuator/health"
    }
});

const albListener = albTargetGroup.createListener("fargateAlbListener", { port: port, protocol: "HTTP" });

// Define Container image published to the GitHub Container Registry
const service = new awsx.ecs.FargateService("microservice-api-spring-boot", {
    taskDefinitionArgs: {
        containers: {
            microservice_api_spring_boot: {
                image: "ghcr.io/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot:latest",
                memory: 768,
                portMappings: [ albListener ]
            },
        },
    },
    desiredCount: 2,
});

// Export the URL so we can easily access it.
export const apiUrl = albListener.endpoint.hostname;
```

Everything works as expected, but now I need to use a private container image `ghcr.io/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot-private:latest` instead. Switching my code to use the new image, my Fargate Cluster Service keeps stopping and starting new Tasks/Containers endlessly. Looking into my Fargate Cluster's Service' `Task` tab and switching to the `Stopped` Task status I see lot's of `STOPPED (CannotPull...` errors like this:

[image]

If I click into one of the stopped Tasks I see the following `Stopped reason`:

```
CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 1 time(s): failed to resolve ref "ghcr.io/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot-private:latest": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

So how can I configure access to a private Container Registry (here GitHub Container Registry) using Pulumi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the AWS docs there's a detailed guide on [how to grant ECS EC2 & Fargate launch type Tasks access to private Registries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html). Derived from that there are 4 steps to take:

0. Obtain Token or credentials to access private Container Registry
1. Create AWS Secrets Manager Secret containing Token/Creds to private Registry
2. Craft Task Execution Role (using aws.iam.Role) containing inlinePolicy for private Container Registry access
3. Enhance awsx.ecs.FargateService to use our Task Execution Role & Secret ARN in repositoryCredentials

---

**0. Obtain Token or credentials to access private Container Registry**

If you don't already have them, you'll need to create an Access Token or credentials inside our private Registry so that an external service is able to access it. With GitHub Container Registry for example we need to create a Personal Access Token ([see docs here](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry#authenticating-to-the-container-registry)) using the `read:packages` scope as a minimum:

[image]

---

**1. Create AWS Secrets Manager Secret containing Token/Creds to private Registry**

[Now head over to the AWS Secrets Manager console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html#private-auth-enable) at https://console.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/ and create a new Secret via the `Store a new secret` button. In the GUI choose `Other type of secrets` and `Plaintext` - and then fill in your private Registry credentials as JSON:

```
{
  "username": "yourGitHubUserNameHere",
  "password": "yourGitHubPATHere"
}
```

Select `Next` and provide a Secret Name like `githubContainerRegistryAccess`. Hit Next again and leave `Disable automatic rotation` as the default. Next again and hit `Store` to create the Secret. Finally copy the Secret ARN like `arn:aws:secretsmanager:awsRegionHere:yourAccountIdHere:secret:githubContainerRegistryAccess-randomNumberHere` to your notepad or editor for later reference.

---

**2. Craft Task Execution Role (using aws.iam.Role) containing inlinePolicy for private Container Registry access**

[As the docs tell us](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html#private-auth-iam) we need to add the permission to access the Secrets Manager Secret as Inline Policy to the Fargate Tasks Execution Role. Now as the `new awsx.ecs.FargateService` automatically creates such a Task Execution Role, but we can't access it afterwards really, we need to create the whole thing ourselves. To create the `aws.iam.Role` we can have a look into [the Pulumi docs about it](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/aws/iam/role/). A Pulumi `aws.iam.Role` consists of multiple components, and we need 3 of them:

- `assumeRolePolicy`: I didn't really wanted to define this myself, but the `aws.iam.Role` can't be created without it. It's crucial to choose `"sts:AssumeRole"` as the `Action` and `"ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"` as the Service Principal.
- `inlinePolicies`: This array will take our InlinePolicy which the Task needs to access the Secrets Manager Secret (aka the whole point of this Role creation here). It's [exactly the same as described in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html#private-auth-iam) - really keep an eye on the correct `arn` names inside `Resources`. One of the two is exactly our Secrets Manager Secret ARN!
- `managedPolicyArns` contains the default Policies attached to a Fargate Task by Pulumi (I simply had a look into the AWS Console to find their arns).

Here's the Pulumi code we need for the InlinePolicy to be defined correctly:

```
const taskExecutionRole = new aws.iam.Role("microservice-api-spring-boot-execution", {
    assumeRolePolicy: {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        ]
    }, inlinePolicies: [
        {
            name: "ghcr-secret-access",
            policy: JSON.stringify({
                Version: "2012-10-17",
                Statement: [
                    {
                        Effect: "Allow",
                        Action: [
                            "kms:Decrypt",
                            "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
                        ],
                        Resource: [
                            "arn:aws:secretsmanager:awsRegionHere:yourAccountIdHere:secret:githubContainerRegistryAccess-randomNumberHere",
                            "arn:aws:kms:awsRegionHere:yourAccountIdHere:key/key_id"
                        ]
                    }]
            })
        },
    ],
    managedPolicyArns: [
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy",
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
    ]
});
```

---

**3. Enhance awsx.ecs.FargateService to use our Task Execution Role & Secret ARN in repositoryCredentials**

Now this is the final step. We need to use our created Task Execution Role and attach it to our `awsx.ecs.FargateService` using the `executionRole` parameter. And [we also need to provide our Secrets Manager Secret ARN (again) as `repositoryCredentials:credentialsParameter` to our `awsx.ecs.FargateService`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html). This looks somehow like this:

```
// Define Container image published to the GitHub Container Registry
const service = new awsx.ecs.FargateService("microservice-api-spring-boot", { 
    taskDefinitionArgs: {
        containers: {
            blueprint_helloworld: {
                image: "ghcr.io/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot-private:latest",
                memory: 768,
                portMappings: [ albListener ],
                // Access private GitHub Container Registry: we need to provide the Secret ARN as repositoryCredentials
                // see https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/nodejs/pulumi/awsx/ecs/#Container-repositoryCredentials
                repositoryCredentials: {
                    credentialsParameter: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:awsRegionHere:yourAccountIdHere:secret:githubContainerRegistryAccess-randomNumberHere",
                }
            },
        },
        executionRole: taskExecutionRole,
    },
    desiredCount: 2,
});
```

Now a `pulumi up` should bring up your Fargate Tasks as expected, since they're now able to pull the container images from the private GitHub Container Registry. Inside the AWS ECS Cluster view you should see your running Tasks:

[image]

Comment: how do you do this when you use the GITHUB_TOKEN rather than generating your personal token in GitHub?

Comment: Accessing the GitHub Container Registry from *within* GitHub Actions has been made easier where you don't need to generate a PAT anymore and can directly use the `GITHUB_TOKEN`. But AFAIK to access the GitHub Container Registry from *outside* of GitHub Actions context (e.g. here from AWS Fargate), you still need the PAT.

Comment: makes sense. thank you